# When should I use the *Central Limit Theorem*?

Tags: probability, statistics, central-limit-theorem

I am facing the following question:

Assume you have invited a $100$ people to a party. The probability that one would decide to come to the party is $0.75$.

What is the probability that more 70 but not more than 80 people will decide to come to your party?

I can tell that if $X$ is the number of people that have decided to come to the party, I can easily say that $X \sim Bin(100, 0.75)$.

I can use that to tell what is $P(70 < k=x <80)$

Why would I want to use the *Central Limit Theorem* and move to $N \dot{\sim}(100\cdot0.75, 100\cdot0.25)$?

Comment: In the old days binomial computations of the type you describe were unpleasant. Now any number of programs, even free ones, will do it.

Comment: @AndréNicolas since calculators didn't have the nCr option?

Comment: Since there were no electronic calculators. The Normal approximation calculation can be done quickly with a normal table and a slide rule, or log table.

Comment: when you say the old days you mean the **old days** :-)

Comment: It is important to be aware that a sum of iid nice rv is nearly normal. From the computational point of view, binomial is no longer the best example. One cannot expect texts to keep up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a good calculator that will be able to handle binomial coefficients with $n= 100$, it's feasible, if a bit tedious, to compute and add $10$ probabilities.  But what if you invited $10$ million people and wanted to know the probability that between $7,490,000$ and $7,500,000$ would come?

(I guess if you can afford to throw that big a party, you can afford to hire someone to compute that for you)

Comment: I just need to calculate $P(X=71) + P(X=72) + ... + P(X=79)$ so in my case the use of the theorem is a bit weak right? You (and Andre)  are saying that the normalization helps us calculate binomial calculations for larger numbers? Is that it?